# php - login by google using google/appclient works only when not using a client_id

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, google-authentication, google-signin

I'm building a login by google for a mobile app and I have this weird issue that took from me 2 days to debug!!

That's the method `verifyIdToken($id_token)` always returning false and the token is valid ( that comes from my mobile app ) as I have tested with google apies oAuth2

By Luck, I removed the client_id and lifted as empty str and walaa it works returning a user response payload

I can't understand why is that!! I'm using the same client_id on a node app in production and it's working fine ( access token not id token ), and I'm moving from node to PHP so I used the same client_id to test.

The Code:

```php
$params = $request->get_params();
$token  = isset( $params['token'] ) ? $params['token'] : false;

if ( ! $token ) {
    return new \WP_Error( 'no-token', __( 'No token received from Google', 'vivant' ) );
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'Google_Client' ) ) {
    include_once plugin_dir_path( HEADLESS_FILE ) . '/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php'; // change path as needed
}

$client = new \Google_Client();  // works without a client_id and not working with a client_id

// $clinet->setClientSer
try {
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken( $token );

    return $payload; // for debugging the value
    if ( $payload ) {
        // whatever
    } else {
        return new \WP_Error( 'invalid-token', __( 'Token is not valid', 'vivant' ) );
    }
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
    return new \WP_Error( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
}
```